# How to open navbar ngbDropdown on hover?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

In Angular 2 ng-bootstrap is it possible to open a bootstrap `navbar` `ngbDropdown` on hover?

Comment: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1117

Answer (score 3):

call the opening and closing function on mouse enter event and mouse leave event

```
(mouseenter)="$event.stopPropagation(); myDrop.open();"
(mouseleave)="$event.stopPropagation(); myDrop.close();"
```